# How to get partial object from self referencing entity

Tags: playframework, entity, one-to-many, ebean

How can I get partial result from self referencing entity that has a parent-child pair relationship?

I've tried to get whole entity objects and then refactors it into partial object.

I also tried FetchGroup, select partial columns and others.

But none of them worked. When it retrieves the children, the whole object changes to bring entire entity.

```
@Entity
public class someClass extents Model {

    public String name;
    public String code;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    public Menu parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    @JsonManagedReference
    public Set<someClass> children;

    other columns and getters/setters.
}
```

Here is finder I use

```
public static List<someClass> findInTree() {
    find
            .query()
            .where()
            .isNull("parent")
            .findList();
}
```

and I can see queries running

```
[info] o.j.StatementLogger - select t0.id, t0.code, t0.name from some_entity t0 where t0.parent_id is null  and t0.is_active = Y  and  to_timestamp('2019-04-04 19:05:54.333', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff3') between t0.start_date and t0.end_date ;
[info] o.j.StatementLogger - select t0.parent_id, t0.id from some_entity t0 where (t0.parent_id) in (1, 2, 3, 4, 1 ) ;
[info] o.j.StatementLogger - select t0.id, t0.code, t0.name from some_entity t0 where t0.id in (5, 6, 5, 5, 5 ) ;
[info] o.j.StatementLogger - select t0.parent_id, t0.id from some_entity t0 where (t0.parent_id) in (5, 6, 5, 5, 5 ) ;
[info] o.j.StatementLogger - select t0.id, t0.code, t0.name from some_entity t0 where t0.id in (7, 8, 7, 7, 7 ) ;
[info] o.j.StatementLogger - select t0.parent_id, t0.id from some_entity t0 where (t0.parent_id) in (7, 8, 7, 7, 7 ) ;
```

and result was

```
"someClass":[  
         {  
            "id":1,
            "code":"test1",
            "name":"test1",
            "children":[  

            ],
            ... rest of columns
         },
            ... 
         {  
            "id":4,
            "code":"test1",
            "name":"test1",
            "children":[  
               {  
                  "id":5,
                  "code":"test1",
                  "name":"test1",
                  "children":[  
                     {  
                        "id":7,
                        "code":"test1",
                        "name":"test1",
                        "children":[  

                        ],
                     },
              ... rest of columns

                  ],
            ... rest of columns

               },
...
]
```

I'm worrying about recursive queries consuming too much resource when it became bigger.

And also, I want to use this practice to other entities that have different relationship.

Expecting result looks like below.

```
"someClass":[  
         {  
            "id":1,
            "code":"test1",
            "name":"test1",
            "children":null,
         },
            ... 
         {  
            "id":4,
            "code":"test1",
            "name":"test1",
            "children":[  
               {  
                  "id":5,
                  "code":"test1",
                  "name":"test1",
                  "children":[  
                     {  
                        "id":7,
                        "code":"test1",
                        "name":"test1",
                        "children":null,
                     },
                  ],
               },
...
]
```

I want to remove all unnecessary data from result and hopefully reduce retrieve mapped queries to optimize.

Is there best practice or examples that I can look up?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I do this as following

```
[ModelClassName].find.select("field1, field2, ...")

.where
...
....
.findList();
```

where find is

```
public static final Finder<primaryKeyType, ClassName> find = new Finder<>(ProClassNameducts.class);
```

notice that Field name is like in your model class not in DB.

hope this help